# Can't Enable PHP Extensions on php.ini on App Engine for Laravel

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel, php-extension, php-ini

I'm trying to enable some php extensions needed by Laravel. The documentation for the `php.ini` file (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/php_ini) says to place a php.ini file in the root of the application.

This is what my `php.ini` looks like:

```
extension=openssl.so
extension=pdo.so
extension=tokenizer.so
extension=mbstring.so
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "php_sapi_name, php_uname"
```

When I deploy it, my log says:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/base/php_runtime/modules/openssl.so' - /base/php_runtime/modules/openssl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/base/php_runtime/modules/pdo.so' - /base/php_runtime/modules/pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/base/php_runtime/modules/tokenizer.so' - /base/php_runtime/modules/tokenizer.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/base/php_runtime/modules/mbstring.so' - /base/php_runtime/modules/mbstring.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I've tried changing the way I've formatted the extensions in `php.ini`:

```
extension="openssl.so"
extension="openssl.dll"
extension="php_openssl.so"
extension="php_openssl.dll"
```

I've tried it with quotations, and without them. With spaces in between them, without them. I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Are those libraries available? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#dynamically_loadable_extensions It seems like they aren't (I don't know why though).

Comment: I've figured out the problem. 

The documentation says that these modules are already loaded. And only `imagick`, `curl`, `mongo`, and `intl` need to be explicitly added to `php.ini`.

Comment: Removing the `extension=*` lines fixed it.

Comment: If you can, post that as the answer.

Comment: Posted an answer with my solution.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem.

When you serve the application locally and when you deploy, App Engine uses the `php.ini` file in the root of your application.

The problem was that when I ran it locally, I needed to have the `extension=*` lines in `php.ini` to load the necessary extensions. When I deployed it with those lines in `php.ini`, I got the error I reported in my question.

My solution is to have two different versions of `php.ini`: `php.ini.local` and `php.ini.dev`.

**`php.ini.local`:**

```
extension=mbstring.so
extension=pdo.so
extension=openssl.so
extension=tokenizer.so
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "php_sapi_name, php_uname"
```

**`php.ini.dev`:**

```
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "php_sapi_name, php_uname"
```

And use a Makefile to replace php.ini with either the dev version or local version depending on what I need.

**`Makefile`:**

```
deploy:
    cp php.ini.dev php.ini
    # Code used to deploy
serve:
    cp php.ini.local php.ini
    # Code used to serve locally
```